# Australian comedy movie where a guy has house near airport

Tags: identify-this-movie

I think the movie should be somewhere between late 80's and early 90's. I watched this movie in my friend's netflix account.

The guy has three sons and a daughter, and one son would be in jail. They have a house just besides the airport.

I think the movie is about the guy trying to save the house from the airport authorities who wants the land for airport expansion. I also remember a scene where the family would be having dinner together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its definitely [The Castle (film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Castle_%28film%29).

> From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118826/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) plot summary
>
> A Melbourne family is very happy living where they do, near the
> Melbourne airport (according to Jane Kennedy, it's "practically their
> back yard"). However, they are forced to leave their beloved home, by
> the Government and airport authorities. 'The Castle' is the story of
> how they fight to remain in their house, taking their case as far as
> the High Court.

Comment: Are we good or what? :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would be the Australian film "[The Castle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118826/)". Many of your plot elements match, except for the son in jail.

[Wiki entry and summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Castle_%28film%29).